# How to fix the issue "PyPI-test not found in .pypic" when submit package to PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, python-2.6, easy-install, pypi

I followed the guide [How to submit a package to PyPI](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) to submit one package.
It throwed the error below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 27, in 
        'Programming Language :: Python',
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/register.py", line 9, in run
        _register.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/register.py", line 33, in run
        self._set_config()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/register.py", line 84, in _set_config
        raise ValueError('%s not found in .pypirc' % self.repository)
    ValueError: PyPI-test not found in .pypirc
```

My .pypirc file context is:

```
    [distutils] # this tells distutils what package indexes you can push to
    index-servers =
        PyPI # the live PyPI
        PyPI-test # test PyPI

    [PyPI] # authentication details for live PyPI
    repository: https://PyPI.python.org/PyPI
    username: {{username}}
    password: {{password}}

    [PyPI-test] # authentication details for test PyPI
    repository: https://testPyPI.python.org/PyPI
    username: {{username}}
```

My OS env is

```
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

and python env is

```
Python 2.6.6
```

.

What's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: I believe the key point is where the .pyirc file should go. See my answer below.

Answer (score 23):

Some pitfalls to avoid in order to make this work:

The `.pypirc` file is expected inside the `HOME` directory. This is true for Windows and Unix.

If it's not working, it's because the .pypirc file is not found at the path indicated by the `HOME` variable.

On Windows, to know what your path is:

- With PowerShell (if you are using `pew` to manage virtualenv for instance),  `echo $HOME`.
- With default Windows console, `echo %HOMEPATH%` (yes, talk about "portability")

Then place the .pypirc file right at that path.

As for the file, **don't forget the distutil part, otherwise it won't work**.
Your file should be **EXACTLY** like that:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository = https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username = <your user name goes here>
password = <your password goes here>

[pypi]
repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username = <your user name goes here>
password = <your password goes here>
```

My intuition tells me to not customize the pypi repository name, not sure it works otherwise.

Then, when you run the command, simple provide the `-r` (repository) flag with `pypitest`

```
python setup.py register -r pypitest
```

And that should do the trick.

Comment: It works. The issue for me was the location of my `.pypirc` file.

Comment: @nu-everest The python packaging user guide is really not clear on this, I'm not even sure it mentions where the file should go. Glad you could solve your issue.

Comment: I want to highlight this part of the answer `As for the file, don't forget the distutil part, otherwise it won't work. Your file should be exactly like that:`

Comment: @Clintm I've edited the post to highlight it some more, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 13):

Make sure your .pypirc file is in your /home directory.

Comment: That gives me `python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

When I got this error, I changed my .pypirc file to:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  test

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: {{username}}
password: {{password}}

[test]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: {{username}}
password: {{password}}
```

and then I ran:

```
 python setup.py register
```

instead of:

```
python setup.py register -r pypitest
```

This prompted me for my username and password which I entered and it successfully registered. Note I was following [Peter Downs' Guide](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html)

I realized this doesn't upload to pypitest, but I still managed to register my module to pypi using this method.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Where you ever able to find a solution that allowed you to upload to testpypi?  I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to, sorry.

Comment: @Einstein: check out my answer. There is a clear issue with your command, you are typing `-r pypitest` but your repo is titled `test`. This cannot work

Comment: @nueverest: Look up my answer, and bring some feedback if needed. I believe it should fix your problems

Answer (score 2):

I replaced "PyPI"/"PyPItest" both to lowercase letters: "pypi"/"pypi-test". The error disappeared, but prompt another error:

```
 Server response (403): You are not allowed to store 'mypackage' package information.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the comments here since distutils doesn't parse them properly:

```
index-servers =
       PyPI # the live PyPI
       PyPI-test # test PyPI
```

So just:

```
index-servers =
       PyPI
       PyPI-test
```

Or maybe even better don't use mixed case and dashes for the repository names, as Junchen suggests. With the current version it should work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I used pypitest, rather than pypi-test. Works like charm.

I follow the instruction by [Peter Downs](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html)